# Rotate an NSImage by arbitrary angle and supporting Retina displays

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display, nsimage

I need to rotate an `NSImage` by an arbitrary angle. For the iOS version of my app, I hacked together the following solution from several sources I found on the internets:

```
@implementation UIImage (ut_rotate)

- (instancetype)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees{
    CGFloat scale   = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; // support retina displays
    float newSide   = self.size.width; // square img
    CGSize size     =  CGSizeMake(newSide, newSide);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSide/2.0f, newSide/2.0f);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, _heading * M_PI/180.0);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-newSide/2.0f, -newSide/2.0f, newSide, newSide), _image.CGImage);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context) scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
}
@end
```

Note that this hack supports retina display.

For Cocoa, I found the canonical solution on one of the internets:

```
@implementation NSImage (ut_rotate)

- (NSImage*)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    // Calculate the bounds for the rotated image
    // We do this by affine-transforming the bounds rectangle
    NSRect imageBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [self size]};
    NSBezierPath* boundsPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageBounds];
    NSAffineTransform* transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    [transform rotateByDegrees:-1.0 * degrees];// we want clockwise angles
    [boundsPath transformUsingAffineTransform:transform];
    NSRect rotatedBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [boundsPath bounds].size};
    NSImage* rotatedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rotatedBounds.size] ;

    // Center the image within the rotated bounds
    imageBounds.origin.x = NSMidX(rotatedBounds) - (NSWidth(imageBounds) / 2);
    imageBounds.origin.y = NSMidY(rotatedBounds) - (NSHeight(imageBounds) / 2);

    // Start a new transform, to transform the image
    transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];

    // Move coordinate system to the center
    // (since we want to rotate around the center)
    [transform translateXBy:+(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2)
                        yBy:+(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];
    // Do the rotation
    [transform rotateByDegrees:-1.0 * degrees];
    // Move coordinate system back to normal (bottom, left)
    [transform translateXBy:-(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2)
                        yBy:-(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];

    // Draw the original image, rotated, into the new image
    // Note: This "drawing" is done off-screen.
    [rotatedImage lockFocus];
    [transform concat];
    [self drawInRect:imageBounds fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0] ;
    [rotatedImage unlockFocus];

    return rotatedImage;

}
@end
```

Problem is: a) results look blurry already on non-retina displays b) doesn't support retina.

I found something about substituting code between `lockFocus` and `unlockFocus` with [block-based drawing methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/CapturingScreenContents/CapturingScreenContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH10-SW32) but don't understand it.

I'm looking for a solution that produces sharper images and supports retina. For my needs  only square source images have to be supported on OS X 10.9 and later.

Comment: Do you really need a modified image object or is enough to *display* the image rotated?

Comment: I think I need a modified image because I want to assign it to the `image` property of an `MKAnnotationView`. Also, the rotational angle actually is the heading of an aircraft, which will be continuosly updated and need the zero degree reference image.

Comment: See if `[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh]` after the `-lockFocus` reduces the blurriness. To support retina displays, you may need to create your image using the block-based API `+imageWithSize:flipped:drawingHandler:` that draws the original image rotated in the drawing handler.

Comment: @KenThomases a) No change in blurriness. The blurriness seems to be dependend on the angle. b) could you provide code for the block-based method please?

Comment: A certain amount of blurriness is unavoidable when you rotate bitmaps. Each rectangular pixel of the original ends up with parts in each of several pixels in the rotated orientation. So, pixel color values have to be weighted-averaged together with the other pixels that are contributing to each pixel in the new image.

Comment: Yeah but the iOS code does not produce any blurriness...

Answer (score 1):

This is completely untested but may work:

```
@implementation NSImage (ut_rotate)

- (NSImage*)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    // Calculate the bounds for the rotated image
    // We do this by affine-transforming the bounds rectangle
    NSRect imageBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [self size]};
    NSBezierPath* boundsPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageBounds];
    NSAffineTransform* transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    [transform rotateByDegrees:-1.0 * degrees];// we want clockwise angles
    [boundsPath transformUsingAffineTransform:transform];
    NSRect rotatedBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [boundsPath bounds].size};

    // Center the image within the rotated bounds
    imageBounds.origin.x = NSMidX(rotatedBounds) - (NSWidth(imageBounds) / 2);
    imageBounds.origin.y = NSMidY(rotatedBounds) - (NSHeight(imageBounds) / 2);

    NSImage* rotatedImage = [NSImage imageWithSize:rotatedBounds.size flipped:NO drawingHandler:^BOOL (NSRect dstRect){
        // Start a new transform, to transform the image
        NSAffineTransform* transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];

        // Move coordinate system to the center
        // (since we want to rotate around the center)
        [transform translateXBy:+(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2)
                            yBy:+(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];
        // Do the rotation
        [transform rotateByDegrees:-1.0 * degrees];
        // Move coordinate system back to normal (bottom, left)
        [transform translateXBy:-(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2)
                            yBy:-(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];

        // Draw the original image, rotated, into the new image
        [transform concat];
        [self drawInRect:imageBounds fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        return YES;
    }];

    return rotatedImage;

}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't compile. `imageBounds.origin.x` _Read-Only variable is not assignable._ and _Control reaches end of non-void block_

Comment: Well, I said it was untested. ;) I've tweaked it. I hoisted the modification of `imageBounds` out of the block and made the block return `YES`.

Comment: I'll report back once I found someone with a retina screen.

Answer (score 0):

My extension for NSImage, work properly with all degrees

```
- (NSImage *)rotateByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    NSImage *image = nil;
    if (degrees == 0.0)
    {
        image = self;
    }
    else
    {
        CIImage *ciImage = [[[CIImage alloc] initWithData:self.TIFFRepresentation] autorelease];
        CGFloat angle = degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
        CIImage *output = [ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)];
        image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(self.size.width * fabs(cos(angle)) + self.size.height * fabs(sin(angle)), self.size.width * fabs(sin(angle)) + self.size.height * fabs(cos(angle)))] autorelease];
        [image addRepresentation:[NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:output]];
    }
    return image;
}
```